# Appending responses from different APIs

Tags: node.js, api, express, async-await

I have this API for my website. What I want to do is send the `checklist_data` and `data` as a single response from this controller function.

How can I achieve this?

```
const getNumberOfApprovedCreators = (callback) => {
      Pages.find({ status: "ACTIVE" })
        .populate("user")
        .exec(async (err, data) => {
          if (err) return callback(err, 500, null);
          else {
            for await (page of data) {
              let { err, status, checklist_data } = await checklistController.getActions(
                page.user
              );
              
    
            }
            return callback(null, 200, data);
          }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all the `checklist_data` into an array and then put both that data and the other data into an object and make the object what you send back to from the controller:

```
const getNumberOfApprovedCreators = (callback) => {
    Pages.find({ status: "ACTIVE" })
        .populate("user")
        .exec(async (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
              return callback(err, 500, null);
          } else {
            const checklist_results = [];
            for await (page of data) {
              let { err, status, checklist_data } = await checklistController.getActions(
                page.user
              );
              if (err) return callback(err, 500, null);
              checklist_results.push(checklist_data);
            }
            return callback(null, 200, {data, checklist_results});
        }
    });
};
```